# How to apply =image("url") to a range of cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have these bunch of urls in first column... I need to apply the =image("url") to this range of 100 cells. I've been doing it manually and searching for a solution

> PS: nope for this particular scenario I simply cant use =image(cell)
>   and drag down to the entire range. IDKY i need to do this with only
>   =image("url")

Comment: haha.. well I've been using this [formCreator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formcreator/lepgohlbinkefhmmblcjddfameifimbm?utm_source=permalink) to convert spreadhsheets into forms and for some strange reason in the imageURL insert; its working only if I use =image("url") and fails if asked to fetch the image from a cell url.

I've been doing it manually too long to get sick of it & finally thought of taking help:)

Comment: you could try ="=image(""&cellref&"")"        and then copy and paste as values. But it only 1/2 works, as you need to add a space to the end or something to make it convert to a formula. ... Or use google-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. This is basically a question that I asked a few days ago as well. I initially got a solution that could not be applied across a range. Now with this code, you can.

```
// global
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "create URL", functionName: "createURL"}];
  ss.addMenu("URL", menu);
};

function createURL() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<v[0].length;j++) {
      v[i][j] = '=img("'+v[i][j]+'","'+v[i][j]+'")'
    }
  }
  r.setValues(v);  
};
```

You will see the an option for Create URL which will add the link to it.
I believe the above code should work. Please try it